# How to set a negative Align Center X or Y value in Interface Builder in Xcode 6.4?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm trying to set a negative value in Xcode 6.4 in an Interface Builder auto layout constraint as follows:

[image]

If I type "-50.0", Xcode registers the negative value (changes it to "-50"), but defaults to 0 when I close the pop up window. If I type "-50" directly, it instantly changes to 0.

How can I enter negative values? I'm using Xcode Version 6.4 (6E35b), but I'm also experiencing this in Version 7.0 beta 6 (7A192o). I have English as preferred language, region as `Finland - Finnish` and using a Finnish keyboard.

*Edit:* Here's a [video](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5812981/Video%2015.9.2015%2012.56.53.mov) of the behavior.

Comment: You could just set the constant to 50 and the multiplier to -1. That would be my first thought. But as far as i remember it should take negative values.

Comment: Multiplier doesn't take a '-'.

Comment: It seems that somebody else is having the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909547/xcode-6-3-2-cant-enter-negative-values-in-layout-builder-constraints

Comment: I can enter negative values everywhere. Tested it now and it worked for me. :-/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a IBOutlet of specific NSLayoutConstraint and programmatically set whatever value you want.

```
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *layoutConstant;
```

below is the way to change the its value

```
layoutConstant.Constant = -50
```

Comment: Yes, I can do this. I can also open the XML file and manually enter the - there (with Xcode & same keyboard), and it works fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's weird. You should be able to just hit enter and that's it (then esc to close pop up). Do you have any constraint warnings/errors?

Not enough reputation to comment.

Comment: See the video I added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have a button that has a 4 constraints -- Width, height, Align horizontal and Vertical to superview.

I change the Horizontal to a negative and that gives a orange constraint in storyboard showing ambiguity in constraints.
Here [image]

Then I shift the button to -21 (which was the negative value i gave) and it became blue showing everything as ok.
Here [image]

I coloured the background of the button and ran it, and its coming as i set the constraints.
[image]

Comment: What happens if you press *Edit* in the constraint (Align Center X or Align Center Y) and type, say, "-50" and press Enter? For me, it just resets to 0.

Comment: Then in that case, move your view to say -50 in x or y and go to editor and then update current constraints. and that should fix it :)

Comment: Yeah, but shouldn't I be able to enter the negative number directly? :)

Comment: Yes you should, i think, you got some settings issue in xcode or you can check if the "update frames" is checked or not, but that also shouldnt make a difference. Mayb an xcode issue, which should be ok once u update or reinstall it.

OR it might be that you are trying to give a negative value to the `view` of the view controller which wont let you give one i think, instead of a custom view like label or button

Answer (score 0):

Your minus symbol looks longer than usual. Check if you enter correct minus symbol. Or maybe you have some autocorrection.

Comment: Actually, it seems that the - symbol changes into a (longer) hyphen when I type "-50.0". But, if I type "-50" (with a minus symbol), it just changes to 0. This is really weird.

Comment: I don't have autocorrect enabled, and it doesn't do this anywhere else.

Comment: Then you can try to open your xib/storyboard as Source Code and modify your value. To find it set it for example 123.

Comment: 90% sure that problem is with wrong minus symbol or your keyboard layout. Try to use default english keyboard and it should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot, but...

Try Xcode's menu:

`Edit > Format > Substitutions > Show Substitutions`

...and see if "Smart Dashes" is selected.

**Note:** The substitutions menu appears in many apps. You should check it whenever some too-smart autocorrectin gets in your way.

Comment: Smart Dashes is not selected.

Comment: OK... What happens if you copy whatever ends up in the field, and paste it to a plain text file in TextEdit.app? Is it identical to the minus sign?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround (do all of these steps exactly or it won't work):

1. double click the constraint to edit in the dedicated edit view
2. type your negative value with decimals, e.g. -25.0 do not press enter
3. **click outside in the IB canvas** to make the new value take effect.

Verified in XCode 7 & 8. I wasn't able to make this work with the "edit" popup. You only get one chance to enter value with each try or IB will replace it with zero or its positive equivalent - you may have to try this twice, also **do not press enter** since that's another way to make IB ruin your input.

*This is obviously a bug because of the behavior described above, also IB happily produces negative values on its own when you do "Update constraint constants".*